# using a glitch-canvas screenshot as a p5 image background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, p5.js, browser-extension

I'm a student currently working on a browser extension(running on chrome) where I'm using the glitch-canvas and p5 libraries. This extension takes a screenshot of your current webpage and then in a new tab makes a glitched image with it (https://github.com/zky829/viewport-glitcher). I am trying to expand upon the existing extension by adding p5 animations on top of the glitched image. However with the code I have it is making the p5 canvas below the image instead of using the image as a background like I want. This is the code

```
"use strict";
var bg;
var y = 0;
var glitchId = 100;

function setup() {
 bg = loadImage('*?screenshot.html?id=' + glitchId++);
 createCanvas(innerWidth, innerHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(bg);

  stroke(226, 204, 0);
  line(0, y, width, y);

  y++;
  if (y > height) {
    y = 0;
  }
}

function setScreenshotUrl(url) {
    var glitchParams = {
        amount:     Math.random()*99,
        iterations: Math.random()*99,
        quality:    Math.random()*99,
        seed:       Math.random()*99
    };
```

How do I fix this so the image created by the browser extension also functions as the canvas for the p5 drawing?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation to make it more readable.

Comment: fixed! thank you for the heads up